# How to list interfaces satisfied by a type in a CLI?

Tags: go, interface

I'm being unsuccessful in using the following command:

> oracle -pos=$GOPATH/src/path/to/project/vendor/github.com/quickfixgo/quickfix/null_log.go#3 implements

To which I get the error:

> oracle: invalid source position -pos=$GOPATH/src/path/to/project/vendor/github.com/quickfixgo/quickfix/null_log.go#3

I want to list the interfaces satisfied by the `nullLog` struct found on the 3rd line of the package found in the path above.

If `oracle` is the right tool for my problem, how can I use it properly?
If not, is there another tool I can use to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following command:

```
oracle -pos=$GOPATH/src/path/to/project/vendor/github.com/quickfixgo/quickfix/null_log.go:#20 implements
```

Note the ":" and that position is a byte offset in the file.

The oracle tool is intended to be used from an editor plugin where the plugin calculates the offset in the file.

Here's the output when I run the tool using the current version of quickfix:

```
$ oracle -pos=$GOPATH/src/github.com/quickfixgo/quickfix/null_log.go:#20 implements
/Users/muffin/gopath/src/github.com/quickfixgo/quickfix/null_log.go:3:6: struct type nullLog
/Users/muffin/gopath/src/github.com/quickfixgo/quickfix/log.go:4:6:     implements Log
```

Comment: You are correct. Now I get `oracle: no type or method here` when there is a type on that line for sure. Is my command incomplete?

Comment: I guess I'm confused as to what offset means here. An offset of 20 works fine on my machine as well. Why does the offset work when pointing to `func NewNullLogFactory` and not at offset 3 where it points to `type nullLog struct {}`?

Comment: Offset is the index of the byte in the file.

Comment: I just found out `oracle help` includes a link to http://golang.org/s/oracle-user-manual which confirms your explanation. Thank you.